# Error ORA-06502: PL/SQL

Tags: base-de-datos, plsql, oracle-10g

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento:

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE QUERY_EMP
(id IN emp.empno%TYPE, salario OUT emp.sal%TYPE, puesto OUT emp.job%TYPE) 
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT job, sal
  INTO salario, puesto
  FROM emp
  WHERE empno = id;
END QUERY_EMP;
```

Y al llamarlo de esta forma para probarlo con esto:

```
Declare
id emp.empno%TYPE := 7844;
salario emp.sal%TYPE;
puesto emp.job%TYPE;
BEGIN 
    QUERY_EMP(id, salario, puesto);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(salario);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(puesto);
END;
```

Obtengo este error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: error : error de conversión de carácter a número
>   numérico o de valor.

No entiendo por qué salta si el tipo de dato es el mismo y existe en la BD.

Comment: Cómo está definida la tabla `emp`?

Answer (score 3):

He encontrado el error, al hacer el select:

```
....
SELECT sal, job
INTO puesto, salario
....
```

Asigno los valores a las variable que no son, y al tener diferente tipo de dato da error. Lo correcto es:

```
....
SELECT sal, job
INTO salario, puesto
....
```